# Is there an equivalent of an f-string in Google Sheets?

Tags: api, google-sheets, string-interpolation, price, f-string

I am making a portfolio tracker in Google Sheets and wanted to know if there is a way to link the "TICKER" column with the code in the "PRICE" column that is used to pull JSON data from Coin Gecko. I was wondering if there was an f-string like there is in Python where you can insert a variable into the string itself. Ergo, every time the Ticker column is updated the coin id will be updated within the API request string. Essentially, string interpolation

For example:

```
TICKER    PRICE

BTC       =importJSON("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids={BTC}","0.current_price")
```

Comment: Can you describe more ind etails what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm looking to do something very simliar.

Comment: Essentially, is it possible to use string interpolation in a Google Sheet to make requests to an API?

Answer (score 2):

You could use CONCATENATE for this:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en

CONCATENATE function
Appends strings to one another.

Sample Usage
CONCATENATE("Welcome", " ", "to", " ", "Sheets!")

CONCATENATE(A1,A2,A3)

CONCATENATE(A2:B7)

Syntax
CONCATENATE(string1, [string2, ...])

string1 - The initial string.

string2 ... - [ OPTIONAL ] - Additional strings to append in sequence.

Notes
When a range with both width and height greater than 1 is specified, cell values are appended across rows rather than down columns. That is, CONCATENATE(A2:B7) is equivalent to CONCATENATE(A2,B2,A3,B3, ... , A7,B7).
See Also
SPLIT: Divides text around a specified character or string, and puts each fragment into a separate cell in the row.

JOIN: Concatenates the elements of one or more one-dimensional arrays using a specified delimiter.